# How do I animate, Moving an ImageView on a circular path with certain radius in android?

Tags: android, animation, rotation, move, image-rotation

Please Find the attachment for my image.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_c-SDSO63obS0ZyQ1dsOXdUQmc/edit?usp=sharing

My task is, animate that GONG type of image up to some time with clock wise and anti clock wise.

For that i did some coding in animation but i didn't succeed. I am using both translate and rotate.

```
     <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="1500" />
```

and rotate functions,

```
      <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="600"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
```

Actually my idea is in a specific time i want to move with specific angle. But i don't know the correct way to solve this task.

Please help me. sorry for my English.

All answers are acceptable

Thanks

Shankar

Comment: hey, did you try doing this with only translate?? add toYDelta and also fromYDelta and reverse the animation and set the repeatcount to infinite.

Answer (score 0):

You have divided a circle in 12 parts in that image and that equals to 30 degrees per segment.
you have to rotate it  like this to look proper

```
 rotateDegree=[steps]*30;
```

use `AlarmManager` to trigger animation in specific time

EDIT:

to move your image in circular path with a radius you have to give a different pivot x and y

you can find it by tryng with

```
 pivotX= 0 and pivotY=(negative value)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Really, I can't get you.  where can i add rotateDegree=[steps]*30  In rotate xml file it is not possible.

Comment: Well, this is what i get from your question. Maybe you will get better answers if you improve this question.

Comment: Sorry, Ercan... My task is Moving an ImageView on a circular path with certain radius.. this is my task.